# Different behavior for same script on 2 different machines

Tags: powershell

I have a "stupid" question about a simple power shell script, when I execute the below script on my Windows 10 PC and on a 2012R2 server I don't have the same result.

Let's say I have 5 folders named 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 in c:\temp.

when I execute the script:

```
$test = Get-Childitem -path "C:\temp" | Sort-Object {$_.Name} -Descending | Select-Object -first 1
Write-Host $test
```

On my Win10 pc it returns "5", and on a 2012R2 server it return "1"...

The only difference I can see is the power version, I have the version 5 on my PC and version 4 on the server. But I don't think that is the root cause. I would like to understand what is happening as the final goal will be to delete this folder so I don't want to delete the wrong one.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: remove { }, this is meant for a scriptblock => Sort-Object $_.Name -Descending

Comment: Try `$test = Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Temp" -Directory | Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Do you only have folders in both directories on both systems? Is the contents of "C:\temp" identical for both systems, was this a copy or were they created manually?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it worked !

Comment: After more test it was working with my version as well, I did not do my initial test correctly... I wasn't testing exactly as described in my post, the content of c:\temp wasn't exactly the same on both machines and messed up my result.